# Binding a control's x:Name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

When I add

```
    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding SettingName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
```

Everuthing is ok. But when

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="{Binding SettingTextBlockName}"  Text="{Binding SettingName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,-2,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
```

constructor are breaking.

But I need different names in all elements.

Answer (score 9):

`x:Name` is a special property. As a matter of fact it's not a property at all, it's an attribute that maps the name or id property of the element to `x:Name`. Binding only works when applied to a `DependencyProperty`, so it cannot work on `x:Name`. It must be set manually.

If you want to distinguish between objects in runtime, you can set the `Tag` attribute, which tolerates everything.

more on `x:Name`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752290.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`FrameworkElement.Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) property, according to MSDN

> FrameworkElement.Tag gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can
>   be used to store custom information about this element.

[What use is the Tag property in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823669/what-use-is-the-tag-property-in-net/3823692#3823692)