# Multiple timers doesnt seem to work on windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, countdown

I have a question concerning windows forms. I have made this countdown which can be seen on the code and pictures below. I have a problem with it though. When i start the first countdown with start and stop, it runs the way it should with hours, minutes and seconds, but as soon as i run the second the first one resets the values to the values put into the second? And it skips a second on both of them.. So it goes from second 53 to 51 on the first and from 52 to 50 on the other one.. Do any of you guys have any ideas how to fix this issue and make them independent of each other which they clearly are now??

Thank you in advance!

```
namespace newtime
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int h;
        private int m;
        private int s;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "0";
            }
            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                textBox2.Text = "0";
            }
            if (textBox3.Text == "")
            {
                textBox3.Text = "0";
            }

            h = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            m = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            s = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            s = s - 1;
            if (s == -1)
            {
                m = m - 1;
                s = 59;
            }
            if (m == -1)
            {
                h = h - 1;
                m = 59;
            }
            if (h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Times up!", "Timer");
            }
            string hh = Convert.ToString(h);
            string mm = Convert.ToString(m);
            string ss = Convert.ToString(s);
            textBox1.Text = hh;
            textBox2.Text = mm;
            textBox3.Text = ss;
        }

        private void btnStop1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
        }

        private void btnStart2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (textBox4.Text == "")
            {
                textBox4.Text = "0";
            }
            if (textBox5.Text == "")
            {
                textBox5.Text = "0";
            }
            if (textBox6.Text == "")
            {
                textBox6.Text = "0";
            }
            h = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
            m = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
            s = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);
            timer2.Start();
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            s = s - 1;
            if (s == -1)
            {
                m = m - 1;
                s = 59;
            }

            if (m == -1)
            {
                h = h - 1;
                m = 59;
            }

            if (h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0)
            {
                timer2.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("Times up!", "Timer");
            }

            string hh = Convert.ToString(h);
            string mm = Convert.ToString(m);
            string ss = Convert.ToString(s);
            textBox4.Text = hh;
            textBox5.Text = mm;
            textBox6.Text = ss;
        }

        private void btnStop2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have two timers, but you only have one set of `h`, `m`, `s` variables, which you overwrite constantly

Comment: this is where you need to use the debugger and step through your code have you don't that part at least..

Comment: Whenever you see yourself repeating code like that, you ought to instantly think "I probably need a class".  A UserControl will do fine here.

Answer (score 1):

As the other posters have pointed out, you only have one copy of `h`, `m`, and `s` that are shared by all timer event handlers.  This means they will overwrite each others' work, as you are currently seeing. The obvious fix is to create a different copy of `h`, `m`, and `s` for each timer.

However, I'd like to point out that you can solve this problem with one timer only.  The program just needs to record the time (obtained from `System.DateTime.Now`) when the user clicks each "Start" button and store it in a variable (one for each timer display).  Then, on an ongoing basis, it just needs to compute the difference between the current time and the (stored) start time for each. The ongoing behavior could be triggered by a single timer and a loop.

It's best to avoid having a lot of different timers running in your application, because then you have to worry about starting, stopping, and disposing each one individually.

Here is a rough draft to give you the idea, it may need a tweak or two to compile.

```
struct TimerStatus
{
    DateTime StartTime;
    bool IsRunning;
}

TimerStatus[] _timers = new TimerStatus[10];


void Start1_Click()
{
    _timers[1].StartTime = System.DateTime.Now;
    _timers[1].IsRunning = true;
}

void Stop1_Click()
{
    _timers[1].IsRunning = false;
}

void Start2_Click()
{
    _timers[2].StartTime = System.DateTime.Now;
    _timers[2].IsRunning = true;
}

void Stop2_Click()
{
    _timers[2].IsRunning = false;
}

void OneAndOnlyTimer_Tick()
{
    for (int i=0; i<=_timers.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        if (_timers[i].IsActive) 
        {
            TimeSpan ts = System.DateTime.Now - _timers[i].StartTime;
            DisplayTimer(i, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);  //You will need to write the method that does the display
        }
    }
}
```

For extra credit you could even use the same click handler for all the buttons ( you can identify the array index using the control's [Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823669/what-use-is-the-tag-property-in-net) property).  But that is outside the scope of my answer.