# Control.s Tag. When should I use it?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I see my company working code, I sometimes see the code "Tag" member of Controls. My co-workers use it as a name tag. But the Controls have already a "Text", "Name" thingy properties. When I see the code, It looks fine to call the Controls with other properties.

I feel somewhat the "Tag" property is not for use of only giving the Control a specific name. So I looked up MSDN for information about it.

They say "Tag" is an Object that can store any data like class. And get the data fast from the tag property. I want to know when is the case should a programmer use it for? Can anyone help me with an example situation and codes?

By the way what are those attributes for? It seems those make the tag more special.

```
[System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter(typeof(System.ComponentModel.StringConverter))]
public object Tag { get; set; }
```

Comment: it can help you associate the control with some other object, so you don't have to define there relationships otherwise. but this looks like some grammer suger for me(and no strong typing makes it hard to get errors when compiling). i'd rather avoid use `Tag` and explicitly define the relationship elsewhere.

Comment: Actually `Tag` is an ancient property to be used however the developer want. I had been using it to categorize the controls. For instance, the CRUD buttons must be `disable` when no entity is active. By querying the controls which are tagged by "CRUD", I could find them.

Comment: The Tag Property is just a multi-purpose *container* for whatever data you may want to associate to the instance of a Control. -- The `Bindable` attribute is not special, all Properties that are meant to support DataBinding (or the other way around) are decorated with that attribute -- `StringConverter` is just a base converter that other converters can use. -- You can probably find all this information in the Docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What use is the Tag property in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823669/what-use-is-the-tag-property-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag can be used for anything you like, common use cases

- when a lot of controls share the same click handler
- tag on list / tree items that let you associate data with the clicked object (a customer object in a list of customers say)

The name nor text is usable in the second case